# Elevate a script with parameters

Tags: powershell, uac

I have a Powershell script with parameters that I'd like to be able to self-elevate.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="cp")]
    [Switch]
    $copy = $false,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="mv")]
    [Switch]
    $move = $false
)
# Elevate if required
if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
  if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
    $Cmd = (
      '-File',
      "`"$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)`"",
      $MyInvocation.BoundParameters
    )
    $ProcArgs = @{
      FilePath = 'PowerShell.exe'
      Verb = 'RunAs'
      ArgumentList = $Cmd
    }
    Start-Process @ProcArgs
    Exit
  }
}
Set-Location -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot
Write-Host "$copy"
Pause
```

If I comment out the `param` block and run `script.ps1 -copy`, an elevated Powershell window opens and prints out `Press enter to continue`, i.e. it works.

If I comment out the `if` statement, the current window outputs `True`, i.e. it also works.

If I run the whole thing though, the elevated windows opens for a split second, then closes ignoring `Pause` with no output anywhere.
I want the elevated window to open and print out `True`.

Comment: The `@()` is the *sub-expression* operator, which you don't necessarily need since your arguments in `$cmd` are already comma separated, but I thought I'd share; because you're using just the regular *grouping operator* `()` is why I mention it. Anyways, you can try adding a `Start-Transcript` and seeing the results. It should capture the error message and output it to a file.

Comment: You're passing the _string_ `System.Management.Automation.PSBoundParametersDictionary` as argument instead of passing the actual switch parameter.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I use `()` so I could align the elements vertically. No output in transcript, unfortunately. It just shows `script.ps1 -copy`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for the heads up! I've updated the post. That doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on Linux and worked for me but couldn't test on Windows, I don't see other way around having to manipulate the `$PSBoundParameters` into *strings* to pass the arguments on `-ArgumentList`.

Below code is meant to be exclusively for testing, hence why I've removed the `if` conditions.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="cp")]
    [Switch]$copy,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="mv")]
    [Switch]$move
)

$argument = @(
    "-File $PSCommandPath"    
    "-$($PSBoundParameters.Keys)"
)

$ProcArgs = @{
    FilePath = 'powershell.exe'
    Verb = 'RunAs'
    ArgumentList = $argument
}

Start-Process @ProcArgs

"Started new Process with the argument: -$($PSBoundParameters.Keys)"
[System.Console]::ReadKey()
Exit
```

Comment: This throws `Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified` at line `Start-Process @ProcArgs` https://i.imgur.com/bOr9SWD.png

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 right, I forgot to change `pwsh` with `powershell.exe` my bad

Comment: That worked! It kept creating new elevated window indefinitely, but after I put the if statements back it created an elevated window successfully and passed the parameter. Many thanks.

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 that's right, the script is recursively calling itself, should've mentioned that sorry lol! happy to help :)